# Combining local and remote ZFS snapshoting [zfs_autobackup]

Tags: snapshot, zfs

I was searching for a simple way of managing my local and remote ZFS snapshots and decided to give [zfs_autobackup](https://github.com/psy0rz/zfs_autobackup) a try.

My goals are to keep a local set of snapshots taken at specific times and send them to a remote machine.

```
zfs set autobackup:local=true tank/data
```

After selecting the source dataset, I created a cron file as follows

```
 0 8-20 * * 1-5  /usr/local/bin/zfs-autobackup local --keep-source 12
 5   20 * * 1-5  /usr/local/bin/zfs-autobackup local --keep-source 1d1w
10   20 * *   5  /usr/local/bin/zfs-autobackup local --keep-source 1w1m
 0    0 1 *   *  /usr/local/bin/zfs-autobackup local --keep-source 1m1y
```

Which doesn't behave the way I expected, deleting older snapshots.

I also wonder which will be the best way to send the snapshots to the remote server, does it make any sense to define another dataset?

```
zfs set autobackup:remote=true tank/data
```

Any ideas?

Comment: Why using 4 lines in crontab? [Documentation](https://github.com/psy0rz/zfs_autobackup#thinning-schedule) use coma separated rules, are you sure each that lines deletes not snapshots kept by other lines? Did you try a `--verbose` run to ensure you set the good way?

Answer (score 0):

im the author if zfs-autobackup.

The answer of Ser is correct: use one zfs command instead of 4. And use conmas to seperate the rules.

Also zfs-backup already keeps local and remote snapshots. So you can just send over the snapshots created by the cronjob. (maby not name them "local", its confusing in that case)

So use the same command as in your cronjob but add the target dataset and --ssh-target.

(also checkout the documention, it explains everything)